# Connect slots QAction dynamically to a function

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qaction

I want to add some `QAction` dynamically from settings file :

```
_settings.beginGroup("openRecent");
QStringList recentList = _settings.childKeys();

foreach(QString recentFile, recentList)
{
    QAction * action = new QAction(_settings.value(recentFile, "empty").toString(), this);
    action->setObjectName(_settings.value(recentFile, "empty").toString());
    connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this,  openFile(action->objectName()));
    _recentFileButtons.append(action);
}
_settings.endGroup();
```

which fails to compile due to this line `connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, openFile(action->objectName()));`

### Question :

How do I connect a QAction to a given function (with parameters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass parameters in that way. I would suggest to do the following:

```
connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openFile()));
```

And in your `openFile()` slot just do:

```
void MyClass::openFile()
{
    QObject *obj = sender();
    QString objName = obj->objectName();
    [..]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can't, not directly

there are 2 options available:

1. use `sender()` to get the sending QObject and use that
2. use a [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsignalmapper.html) which will add a single parameter to the signal

   ```
   signalMapper->setMapping(action, action->objectName());
   connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper,  SLOT(map()));
   ```

   and connect `signalMapper` to `this`:

   ```
   connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), this,  SLOT(openFile(QString)));
   ```

Comment: +1. A signal mapper is the right way to do things. Another possibility is to use a non-exclusive [QActionGroup](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qactiongroup.html), and connect to the group's [triggered](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qactiongroup.html#triggered) signal.